# Got exception 'EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'size' when generating BERT embeddings

Tags: tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am new to huggingface transforms and I have this little test program:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

title = "Today is Monday"
tokens = tokenizer([title], return_tensors="tf", truncation=True, padding=True)
outputs = model(**tokens)
```

It will fail with this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommenders/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommenders/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/../debugpy/server/cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.8.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/nwdata/tests/recommenders/examples/00_quick_start/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    outputs = model(**tokens)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommenders/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommenders/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py", line 962, in forward
    input_shape = input_ids.size()
  File "/anaconda3/envs/recommenders/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 437, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("""
AttributeError: 
        'EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'size'.
        If you are looking for numpy-related methods, please run the following:
        from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
        np_config.enable_numpy_behavior()
```

It will work if I pass `"pt"` to the param `return_tensors`. But I need to set the param to `"tf"` because I will use the result in a tensorflow program.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found the solution.  The solution is to import a different set of classes (**TFAutoModel**, **AutoTokenizer**) to do the job:

```
from transformers import TFAutoModel, AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = TFAutoModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```